# Pass fixture information to normal function

Tags: pytest

How can I pass information in a particular fixture to a normal function i.e. it's not starting with `test_`?

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def my_fixture():
    return 'Hello world!'

def test_one(my_fixture):
    assert my_fixture == 'Hello world!'
```

The above works since the function starts with `test_`. I want something like below:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("my_fixture")
def my_example():
    print(my_fixture())
```

or if I can use it as a variable like:

```
a = pytest.get_fixture("my_fixture")
```

Comment: How is `my_example()` getting called? Execution always *starts* with a `test_*` function, so the simple answer is "add the fixture to your test function and pass it to `my_example`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, create a function, then call that function from a fixture:

```py
import pytest


def hello():
    return "hello"


@pytest.fixture
def my_fixture():
    return hello()


def test_direct(my_fixture):
    # Use fixture directly
    assert my_fixture == "hello"


def test_indirect():
    # Cannot call a fixture, but can call function that make up the fixture
    assert hello() == "hello"
```